# jQuery Trigger keyCode Ctrl+Shift+z & Ctrl+z in wysiwyg textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, wysiwyg, keycode

i was wondering how do i trigger the event keyCode composed by `Ctrl+z` and the event keycode composed by `Ctrl+Shift+z` ?

Comment: for better explanation i would like to know how to create the classic Undo & Redo buttons for a wysiwyg textarea ... the best practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to trigger the event then it should be something like this:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input type=button value=CTRL+SHIFT+Z id=bcsz />
  <input type=button value=CTRL+Z id=bcz />
  <textarea id=t ></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var t = document.getElementById('t'), //textarea
    bcsz = document.getElementById('bcsz'), //button ctrl shift z
    bsz = document.getElementById('bcz'),  // button ctrl z
    csz = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents'), //ctrl shift z event
    cz = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents'); // ctrl z event

csz.initKeyboardEvent(
           'keydown', 
           true,     // key down events bubble 
           true,     // and they can be cancelled 
           document.defaultView,  // Use the default view 
           true,        // ctrl 
           false,       // alt
           true,        //shift
           false,       //meta key 
           90,          // keycode
           0
          );  
cz.initKeyboardEvent(
           'keydown', 
           true,     // key down events bubble 
           true,     // and they can be cancelled 
           document.defaultView,  // Use the default view 
           true,        // ctrl 
           false,       // alt
           false,        //shift
           false,       //meta key 
           90,          // keycode
           0
          );  

bcz.addEventListener('click', function(){
  t.dispatchEvent(cz); 
}, false);

bcsz.addEventListener('click', function(){
  t.dispatchEvent(csz); 
}, false);
```

**[LOOK AT JSBIN LINK](http://jsbin.com/osusiv/edit#javascript,html,live)**

But it seems it doesn't works. I don't have more time to spend on this, but yeah this is kind of a security issue. I would see these docs at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-initEvent) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent) to see if there is a real way to do this.

Comment: @azizpunjani oh sorry your free code source didn't work this time. Maybe you need to read documentations!

Answer (score 12):

Use `e.which` which has been normalized cross browser by jquery.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
      if( e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey ){
         console.log('control + shift + z'); 
      }
      else if( e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey ){
         console.log('control + z'); 
      }          
});
```

Comment: I saw your edit. It's good now. Still ctrl+shift+z fires ctrl+z. This is fix: http://jsfiddle.net/pZgB2/2/

Comment: Good point, edited. Had my else if backwards before. Side note, keyup would work too.

Comment: key up is working if you keep pushing other keys. Not good UX :)

Comment: Can you clarify ? Think of this in context of an editor, pressing ctrl + z would revert.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder sorry i red too fast, what i need is not how to detect the event keycode, is "how do i trigger" the keycode events specified .. :)

Comment: You can't trigger those events, it wouldn't be good from a browser security standpoint. You'd either have to rely on the specific browser implementation or write your own custom solution to persist different states in time.

Comment: uhm can't understand the security problem ... i have a simple textarea then i need 2 links for triggering crtl+z and ctrl+shift+z for repeat or turn back changes on text inside the textarea ... where is the security problem? :/

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder if i can't which is the good solution which all wysiwyg plugins uses to revert or repeat changes ina textarea? does they do not trigger the keycodes below?

Comment: i mean the classics Undo & Redo buttons :P

Comment: The reason browsers don't give you access to those events is because you could override the user e.g a malicious script to undo everything you have done. Like i said you will have to write your own implementation if you want this. If you do find a way to trigger these events i'd be interested to know how you managed to do it. I think most wysiwyg editors just rely on the browser implementation as this is good enough for them.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl and Shift keys are included in key events but keycode is refereeing to which key you press. Ctrl and Shift are control keys and they have their own keys in key events.

For example if you press `Ctrl+Shift+Z` then keydown event would be this:

```
{
    altGraphKey: false
    altKey: false
    bubbles: true
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: true
    charCode: 0
    clipboardData: undefined
    ctrlKey: true
    currentTarget: null
    defaultPrevented: true
    detail: 0
    eventPhase: 0
    keyCode: 90
    keyIdentifier: "U+004C"
    keyLocation: 0
    layerX: 0
    layerY: 0
    metaKey: false
    pageX: 0
    pageY: 0
    returnValue: false
    shiftKey: true
    srcElement: HTMLTextAreaElement
    target: HTMLTextAreaElement
    timeStamp: 1318460678544
    type: "keydown"
    view: DOMWindow
    which: 90
    __proto__: KeyboardEvent
}
```

As you can see there is two key for `Ctrl` and `Shift` keys that are true because those keys were pressed while pressing `Z`.

So you can detect this event like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 90 && event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey){
   // do your stuff
  }
}, false);
```

Note: You should listen to `keydown` for multiple key keyboard shortcuts. `keyup` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are good and work, but for situations where a more dynamic solution would be helpful I have an alternate solution that I use. Recognizing that I'm a little late to the game, this is my solution:

An HTML element to view the effects in:

```
<span id="span"></span>
```

And the script:

```
function Commands()
{
  var k = [], c = {}, b = false;
  var l = l => l.key.toLowerCase();
  var inside = (e) => k.includes(l(e));
  var put = (e) => k.push(l(e));
  var pull = (e) => { k.splice(k.indexOf(l(e)), 1) };
  var add = (e) => { if (!inside(e)) put(e); return 1; };
  var also = (p, i) => k.includes(c[p].combination[i].toLowerCase());
  var set = () => { b = true; return 1; };
  var all = (p) => { var d = true; for (var i = 0; i < c[p].combination.length; i++) d = d && also(p, i); return d; }
  var found = (p) => { set(); all(p); };
  window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => { add(e); for (var p in c) if (all(p)) c[p].action(); return 1; });
  window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => { pull(e) });
  this.setCommand = (n, h, f) => { c[n] = { combination : h, action : f }; return 1; };
  this.getCommands = () => c;
  this.getKeys = () => k;
  this.clearCommands = () => { c = {}; return 1; };
  this.removeCommand = (n) => { return delete c[n];}
}
var commands = new Commands();
commands.setCommand("save", ["control", "shift", "z"], function(){document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "saved";})
commands.setCommand("close", ["alt", "c"], function(){document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "closed";})
```

This is a highly abbreviated version that I use when I know that I am the only one who will need to read through the script. If you think someone else will need to read and understand it, I would suggest using a slightly different version of the script:

```
function Commands()
{
  var keys = [];
  var combinations = {
     save : {
       combination : ["alt", "s"],
       action : function(){ window.alert("here"); return 1; }
     }
   }
   window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
     if (!keys.includes(e.key.toLowerCase()))
     {
       keys.push(e.key.toLowerCase());
     }
     for (var p in combinations)
     {
       var allDown = true;
       for (var i = 0; i < combinations[p].combination.length; i++)
       {
         allDown = allDown && keys.includes(combinations[p].combination[i].toLowerCase());
       }
       if (allDown)
       {
         combinations[p].action();
      }
     }
     return 1;
   })
   window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
     while (keys.indexOf(e.key.toLowerCase()) != -1)
     {
       keys.splice(keys.indexOf(e.key.toLowerCase()), 1);
     }
     return 1;
   })
  this.setCommand = (n, h, f) => { combinations[n] = { combination : h, action : f }; return 1; };
  this.getCommands = () => combinations;
  this.getKeys = () => keys;
  this.clearCommands = () => { combinations = {}; return 1; };
  this.removeCommand = (n) => { return delete combinations[n];}
}
```

Here are the advantages of this approach:

1 ) Someone else working on your code does not need to know how any of the JavaScript you wrote works. You can just have them add and remove commands whenever they need to.

2 ) Commands can be added dynamically (possibly depending on user input).

3 ) Very complex key commands, overloaded commands and other more complex operations might be more difficult with other solutions.

Test it out below:

```js
    function Commands()
    {
      var k = [], c = {}, b = false;
      var l = l => l.key.toLowerCase();
      var inside = (e) => k.includes(l(e));
      var put = (e) => k.push(l(e));
      var pull = (e) => { k.splice(k.indexOf(l(e)), 1) };
      var add = (e) => { if (!inside(e)) put(e); return 1; };
      var also = (p, i) => k.includes(c[p].combination[i].toLowerCase());
      var set = () => { b = true; return 1; };
      var all = (p) => { var d = true; for (var i = 0; i < c[p].combination.length; i++) d = d && also(p, i); return d; }
      var found = (p) => { set(); all(p); };
      window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => { add(e); for (var p in c) if (all(p)) c[p].action(); return 1; });
      window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => { pull(e) });
      this.setCommand = (n, h, f) => { c[n] = { combination : h, action : f }; return 1; };
      this.getCommands = () => c;
      this.getKeys = () => k;
      this.clearCommands = () => { c = {}; return 1; };
      this.removeCommand = (n) => { return delete c[n];}
    }
    var commands = new Commands();
    commands.setCommand("save", ["control", "shift", "z"], function(){document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "saved";})
    commands.setCommand("close", ["alt", "c"], function(){document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "closed";})
```

```css
#span {
  font-size : 25px;
  font-family : Palatino;
  color : #006622;
 }
```

```html
  <span id="span"></span>
```