# Simulate Ctrl+Right Shift user blick JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to "click" on keyboard "Ctrl+Right Shift" with JQuery?

If yes, How can I do it?

*I want to simulate user click on the keys (Ctrl + Right Shift)

Thanks.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: "click on keys" ... is that a mouse event or a keyboard event?

Comment: keyboard event.

Comment: you simply can't do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Trigger keyCode Ctrl+Shift+z & Ctrl+z in wysiwyg textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747536/jquery-trigger-keycode-ctrlshiftz-ctrlz-in-wysiwyg-textarea)

Comment: @Durga - why would any sane person still be running IE8?

Comment: This is an X/Y question. You are asking about an attempted solution instead of telling us what the problem you're attempting to solve is. It's entirely possible there is a better way to achieve what you require, as faking key press events is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with javascript

```
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'Control'}));
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'ShiftRight'}));
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'key':'ShiftRight'}));
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup',{'key':'Control'}));
```

In jQuery you can do:

```
jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keydown', code : 'Control'});
jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', code : 'ShiftRight'});
jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keyup', code : 'ShiftRight'});
jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keyup', code : 'Control'});
```